# SQL Query for Attribute Value(s)

Tags: sql, xml

I have searched everywhere and seem to be having trouble for my specific issue.  I am trying to parse xml values out of our database.  The table is named 'Table.XMLfileData', with a column of XMLData.  The current setup of that column is as such:

[image: XML Data with Column Names]

The setup of the XML itself are all nested in attributes:

[image: XML example]

I want to be able to pull any piece of data out of each of these XML files.  The query that I have found in my research should be something like this:

```
SELECT r.value('@first_name','varchar(60)')
   FROM TableName
CROSS APPLY columnname.nodes('Vehicle_Loan/Applicants/Applicant/first_name') AS  
 x(r)
```

However I retrieve a blank or null value every time.  I am new to this, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: your xpath is wrong in both `.nodes(...)` and `.value(...)`

Answer (score 1):

`.value(...)` requires a single node to work with and **XPath is case sensitive**.

```
SELECT r.value('(./@first_name)[1]','varchar(60)')
   FROM TableName
CROSS APPLY columnname.nodes('Vehicle_Loan/Applicants/Applicant') AS  
 x(r)
```

... working example ...

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'
<Vehicle_Loan>
    <Applicants>
        <Applicant first_name="Matt" />
        <Applicant first_name="Jim" />
    </Applicants>
</Vehicle_Loan>
';

SELECT r.value('(./@first_name)[1]','varchar(60)') AS [FirstName]
    FROM @xml.nodes('Vehicle_Loan/Applicants/Applicant') AS  x(r)
```

... output ...

```
FirstName
---------------
Matt
Jim
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for answering my question and the quick reply.  Using that example, I am able to pull Matt just fine, but I have multiple rows of XML data.  So for example I would want to pull the first name for each row of my XML.  Will this approach hunt through each XML file and pull the information that I'm pointing to in the select statement?

Comment: If you are still using the `CROSS APPLY` over your table's column then yes.  The `.value(...)` works over the XML node passed in which in your case would be the `Applicant` element.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  I was able to get the info I need.  One more question, if I have xml columns with different parent nodes......example 'Vehicle_Loan/Applicants/Applicant'......I might have another type of loan in which the node might go 'Credit_Card/Applicants/Applicant'.  Is there a way with xquery to set the very top node to vary or am I looking a bring in 'NOT NULL' into my query?

Comment: Add `WHERE columnname.exist('/VEHICLE_LOAN') = 1`

Comment: though if you just want applicants without regard for the root you can do... `.nodes('//Applicant')`

Comment: Thank you Matt, you were a grand help.